# javax servlet filter is not working with Mono reactor

Tags: java, servlet-filters, project-reactor

Hi I have created a spring boot application in which I am using Mono reactive.
Now I wanted to do some logging before and after request.. For that I am using `javax.servelet.filter`  like this

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class RequestLoggingFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest= (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpRespnse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        new CustomLogger().getColorLogger().info("dsfsdfsf");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        new CustomLogger().getColorLogger().info("sdfsdfsfsdf");
    }
}
```

But both logs are getting printed simultaneously... then my execution starts. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Reactor doesn't use servlets

Comment: is there any way in reactor to do similar kind of functionality??

Comment: @123 the OP never said he is using WebFlux. He might very well be triggering a reactive chain and using something like a DeferredResult.

Comment: @RAVISINGH what server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposed you use `Spring Webflux` here. Spring webflux comes with his own filter mechanism.

You could use `org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter`

Example

```java
@Component
public class DemoFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, 
      WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {

        // filter logic here.
        return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);
    }
}
```